# How to center activityIndicator to its superview?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface

I am facing issues with centering an activity indicator relative to the screen size and centered inside its superview. This is how it's currently setup:

```
self.activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.gray)
self.tableBackgroundView.addSubview(self.activityIndicator)
self.activityIndicator.center.x = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2
```

The horizontal centering is great, but I'm trying to set the `center.y` to the table view's center. What is the best way to set it to the center vertically in a way that will allow it to center for all screen sizes? The image below shows it without a `center.y` being set explicitly

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The best way to center a UIActivityIndicatorView or in fact any view in the hierarchy is by using the NSLayoutConstraints, you can used them programmatically to center the ActivityIndicator like this.

```
activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.gray)

//This is important.
view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
//If the Activity Indicator is not in the correct z-index you can uncomment this line
//view.bringSubview(toFront: activityIndicator)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    activityIndicator.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableBackgroundView.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0),
    activityIndicator.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableBackgroundView.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0)
])
```

Comment: Sorry, but I tried doing this and the `self.tableBackgroundView` width got squished to the size of activityIndicator. When I changed it to `tableBackgroundView.centerYAnchor` for both constraints, I got the activity indicator on the top left

Comment: oh! but did you try adding the activity indicator to the main view, insted of the tabelBackgroundView

Comment: Well my goal is to position it in the center of the `tableBackgroundView` though, not the actual screen. Wherever the `tableBackgroundView` may be, I want it to be positioned to its center regardless of where in the screen it is positioned

Comment: oh, but that can be achieve too with NSLayoutConstraint... I'll update my question

Comment: Check the new answer, you'll add the activity indicator to the main view but aligned it with the tableBackgroundView

Comment: Why are we adding the activity indicator as a subview of `view` instead of `tableBackgroundView`?

Comment: I tried this and my entire view width got squished!

Comment: mmmm I think the problem is in the rest of your Constraints rather than the ActivityIndicatorView and to answer the other question it was because it it easier to move the object in the main view.

Comment: I don't think so. I think it would be easier to set the `center.y` of the activity indicator to the height of the `tableBackgroundView` relative to the screen size and divide it by 2. How would I go about getting the height of it? The height is dependent on the screen height as well.

Comment: well, if you really want to do it that way you can get the Height by accessing tableBackgroundView.frame.height, but are you sure your tableBackgroundView has the right Constraints? (leading, trailing, top and bottom)

Comment: The `tableBackgroundView` height seems to return the same value for both iPhone 8 and iPhone 11 screens making it optimal for one screen size but not the other. Since the height is based on the top and bottom margins, how would I go about getting the exact height for a particular screen?

Comment: It should't do that, i'm pretty sure that is an error related to constraints (it make sense because if it doesn't change when the screen changes then the constraints is not being applied)

Comment: Ah the problem is that the height is being referenced in `viewDidLoad()`. When I checked the height in `viewWillDisappear`, the height changed

Comment: Found a workaround: set the coordinates `self.activityIndicator.center.x` and `self.activityIndicator.center.y` in `viewDidAppear` and also `self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()` there! This will cause a slight delay in when the animation appears, but seems like the only way to acquire the dynamic height of the view based on the constraints and screen size.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to add:

```
self.activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

In `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` method add this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    activityIndicator.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableBackgroundView.centerXAnchor, constant: 0.0),
    activityIndicator.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableBackgroundView.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0)
])
```